# Prove a bounded operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear bounded operator from Banach space $X$ to Banach space $Y$. If $T(X)$　is second category space, prove that $T(X)$ is closed.

In order to prove that it is closed, we have to show that if $T(x_{n})\rightarrow y$, then there exists some $x\in X$ such that $T(x)=y$. I think we could use the property that $T(X)$ is second category space. But I don't know how to relate these two together.

Comment: What do you mean by : $T(X)$ is of second category?

Comment: If the closure of $T(X)$ is a proper subspace of $Y$ then $T(X)$ is nowhere dense, and cannot be of second category. Therefore $T(X)$ must be dense in $Y$. But $T(X)$ is a linear subspace, if it is second category, it must contain a neighborhood of $0$ (by [Pettis theorem](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FhYGYJtMwcUC&pg=PA110&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Hence $T(X)=Y$, which is closed in $Y$.

Comment: @Riju It is a reference to Baire's second category.  In modern mathematics, we would usually say "residual" or "comeager".  You may want to remind yourself of the statement of [Baire's Category Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Comment: @mike are you familiar with the Open Mapping Theorem and the Closed Graph Theorem?

Comment: Yes,I'm familiar with those two theorem.

Comment: @mike Do you grok the *proof* of the open mapping theorem  (the usual proof relies on Baire's category theorem)?  Can you make hay with that?